# replace words between characters

Tags: java

i am beginner in java , I have the below

```
flybirdy_blue.co

strongwolf_red.po
```

I want such result

`blue`
`red`

```
 String[] parts = csvFile.split("_");
                 String color = parts[1];
```

but it give me wrong result

Comment: parts[1].split(".")

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the `substring()` function to get the value between "_" and "." as follows.

Here you go :

```
String firstcsvFile = "flybirdy_blue.co";
String secondcsvFile = "strongwolf_red.po";
String result = firstcsvFile.substring(firstcsvFile.indexOf("_") + 1, firstcsvFile.indexOf("."));
String result2 = secondcsvFile.substring(secondcsvFile.indexOf("_") + 1, secondcsvFile.indexOf("."));
System.out.println(result);
System.out.println(result2);
```

Output

> blue
>
> red

Comment: can you help me with this ? what if it was `fly_birdy_blue.co` I want the blue as result

Comment: You should ask another question, let me know if you do

Answer (score 1):

you are splitting around "_" , but you need to further split around "." ..

so try ,

```
String[] parts = csvFile.split("_");
String color = parts[1].split(".")[1];
```

Or you could try splitting around _ & . at the same time using "[]" explained [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html) in the "character classes" section:

```
String[] parts = csvFile.split("[_.]");
String color = parts[1];
```

Answer (score 1):

you can use it:

```
String s = "flybirdy_blue.po";
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("(_)(.+)(\\.)");
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(s);
if (matcher.find()) {
    System.out.println(matcher.group(2)); //red
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you should write your own function for better understanding:

```
 public ArrayList<String> splitMyString(String wholeString, char[] splitHere){

    ArrayList<String> response = new ArrayList<String>();
    String temp ="";
    boolean skip = false;

    for(int i = 0 ; i < wholeString.length(); i++){
        for(int j = 0 ; j < splitHere.length; j++){
            if(wholeString.charAt(i) == splitHere[j]){
                response.add(temp);
                temp="";
                skip = true;
            }
        }
        if(skip != true){
            temp = temp +wholeString.charAt(i);
        }else{
            skip = false;
        }
    }
    response.add(temp);
    return response;
}
```